# Sorting files by date in FAR manager

Tags: customization, file-management, file-manager, far

Is there a way to sort files and folders in FAR manager by date created/modified? If so, can it be applied to a specific folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>.

---

If you keep pressed one of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys, the menu at the bottom will change, showing you what the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys will do (in combination with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).

At the top left of each panel the current sorting order is displayed. Capital letter means reversed order (e.g. `n` - name, `C` - inverse created).

[image]

You can also access the help menu (<kbd>F1</kbd> -> `Down` arrow a couple of times -> `Keyboard reference` -> `Panel control commands`):

[image]

I don't think it's possible to fix the sorting folder for just one folder (as opposed to the left or right panel), but the shortcuts are very handy and I just change the order when needed.